# Trying to submit a form with GreaseMonkey, but the page stops working

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, greasemonkey

I need to submit a form on a specific page, and it needs to click a radio button before it submits the form.

I got everything working, however when I let GreaseMonkey submit the form the page just returns a white page. As where if I would click Submit manually, it says 'Wait a second please..' and then goes on to another page.

If neccessary I can give you the URL of the form I am talking about.

This is the script I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[pmmethod=paypal]").click();
$(".submit-button").click();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a event handler is attached to the button, you could try to simulate a mouse click on it using native JavaScript instead of the jQuery method;

```
function simulateClick(node) {
    var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    return node.dispatchEvent(ev);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[pmmethod=paypal]").click();
simulateClick( $(".submit-button")[0] );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know whay tou want...

I've altered the original script and now it will work!

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/153026

Answer (score 0):

To submit a form using JavaScript, use `submit()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[pmmethod=paypal]").click();
    $("#orderform").submit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I try your code, it doesn't do anything.

Like I said, it does submit the form however it just goes on to a white page instead of actually advancing. 
This is the submit button according to Firebug:

`<input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Plaats je bestelling">`

Comment: @user1828398 Please post a link to the form. But also, try: `document.getElementById("form-id").submit()` instead. Make sure to replace `form-id` with the actual id of the form element on the page.

Comment: I actually think you need to be logged in in order to get to the form, sorry. How can I get the ID of the form element?

Comment: If you're using Firebug to inspect the elements, follow the HTML up to where the `<form>` begins. It should look something like `<form id="some-form-id" ...>`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try and replace the `$(".submit-button").click();` in your original code with: `$(".submit-button").form.submit();` also try `$("#orderform").submit();` or `document.getElementById("orderform").submit();`

Comment: I really appreciate your help. This is the ID: `form id="orderform"`